# Redirect all pages to index

Tags: redirect, plesk

I have a simple website with a few pages, I just want all the other requests to be redirected to index page instead of showing 404 page.
My host is a plesk and I've built site with

Answer (score 2):

That is how WordPress works - all requests to non-existent files or directories are redirected to `index.php`, processing second part of URL as an argument for `index.php` script.

On Plesk for Linux, You can add required directives to the additional section in **Domains > example.com > Apache and Nginx Settings**. On Windows - to `web.config` file in the document root.

Apache mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Nginx rewrite:

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
{
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last;
}
```

IIS URL rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```